# WindowsPhone ListBox increase height during scrolling in my emulator and device as well

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

WindowsPhone ListBox increase height during scrolling in my emulator and device as well.I'm using Stack Panel inside ListBox .

This is my`xaml code`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="LstContentTemplate">
                       <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"  BorderThickness="1" Width="480" BorderBrush="Black" >
                            <Grid Height="Auto">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Groupname}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"  FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial"  Foreground="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtgroupname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"  />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"  />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid  Grid.Row="2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mobile}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtmobile" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480"  />
                            </Grid>       
                            </Grid>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: What is the questions?

Comment: You mean that the height is not increasing? Please be clear. This ain't a question.

Comment: height is not auto resizes of stackpanel is two items hold rather than three . It takes space occupie even there is not a vlaue for that textblock.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I got the Solution of that problem , I've visibility Collapsed of those TextBlock in which there is not txet during binding, through a Converter so that TextBlock doesn't occupies there space on list....